# How to access array from nested foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: foreach

How can I access variable which is an array in nested for each loop?

```
 foreach($nodes as $node){
    foreach ($instances as $name => $instance) {
        $items = field_get_items('node', $node, $instance);
        echo $items;
   }
   }
   print_r($items);die;
```

This code is giving me

```
ArrayArray
```

And when I do this instead:

```
foreach($nodes as $node){
    foreach ($instances as $name => $instance) {
        $items = field_get_items('node', $node, $instance);
        print_r($items);die;
   }
   }
```

It gives:

```
Array(
[0]
  [value]
    <p>hbjhbfg</p>
)
```

**How can I access `$items` outside of foreach loop?**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the elements of `$items` in the same way you're looping through `$nodes`.

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    foreach($item as $itemValue) {
        echo $itemValue;
    }
}
```

However, mind that this line:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, $instance);
```

overwrites `$items` at every iteration, therefore when the outer loop ends, you have only the value from last iteration of both "for" loops.
You should append the result of `field_get_items` to `$items`, otherwise the first piece of code is pretty inefficient.

Comment: But why I can't access $items variable outside of the loop?

Comment: @SuagndhKhanna What do you mean you can't access it? You've printed the type of it in your first snippet of code. Is it giving you some kind of error?

Comment: I want the first snippet to get work which is basically returning me an empty array.Generally it shouldn't happen. We can easily access. Let's say, If write echo "hello world"; and print it outside of loop, it will print. Then why the hell it is giving me simply an empty array instead of its values.

Comment: @SuagndhKhanna One thing that might causing this behaviour is, as I mentioned in the answer, the fact that the value of `$items` gets overriden at every loop, so what might happen is that breaking the loop after first iteration as you do in second snippet, gets some values, but when it goes on it simply returns empty values.
Try printing the values of `$items` at each iteration and see what you get.